# Polygon search in django haystack

Tags: django, django-haystack, geo

Documentation says, that polygon search is possible with elastic
http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/spatial.html

However, I can't find any code samples with polygon search implementation. Do you have some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer is here:
https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/pull/720

Request is ready, but still not merged: it lacks docs and tests.